# Load new page on a button click (the button intentionally has no form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

There is a button on a page:

```
<input type="button"
         onclick="clickProcessOrder()"
         id="order-button"
         value="Order">
```

The function it triggers looks like this:

```
function clickProcessOrder() {
    $.get("/checkout");
}
```

The `/checkout` endpoint looks like this:

```
@app.route('/checkout', methods=['GET'])
def checkout():
    return render_template('checkout.html')
```

When I click a button, I can see that the get request successfully comes through:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2019 17:17:05] "GET /checkout HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But I do not get redirected to `checkout.html` page. I stay on the same page.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to get redirected to `checkout.html` page through `/checkout` endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function you can do

```
window.location.href = "checkout.html";
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to my endpoint address - "/checkout" - and it works well for me :)